# AXIOS url is case sensitive

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, axios

I have worked on an Application that uses ASP.NET Core and VueJs. VueJs calls asp.net core controller using AXIOS. Everything is working fine. I was able to publish the site on IIS.
The problem starts when I type url of my web site in lower case.

The url of my web site is

http://10.131.XXX.XXX:94/MyWeb.

Internally  axios calls the controller method on the same url.
for example internally in vue js component, I have written something like this

this.API_URL="http://10.131.XXX.XXX:94/MyWeb

axios.post(this.API_URL + '/UserManagement/GetAllUser', postData);

But if type the following url of my web site

http://10.131.XXX.XXX:94/myweb

then axios is not able to call the controller method and return status code 400 -Bad Request.

I am updating my question. because found a few more hint on issues.

[1] Bad Request error gone if I remove ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute from asp.net core controller method.I add RequestVerificationToken in axios header. but If my request is to myweb this is not avaliable.

[2] My asp.net core controller calls Web API and I am using token authentication there. I keep token in Claim but that Claim is not available when i do request from axios to myweb instead of MyWeb.
Two things on web side using cookie based authentication and for web api using token authentication.

I FIGURE OUT THAT POST REQUEST IS FAILING FROM AXIOS JUST BECAUSE OF ANTIFORGERY TOKEN IN ASP.NET CORE. ALSO WHEN I LOGIN USING LOWERCASE WEBSITE NAME AUTHORIZE ATTRIBUTE REJECTS REQUEST.

I am setting correct token in axios

headers: {
        'RequestVerificationToken': xshrfToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
    }

so my question is that if I change the website name to lower case why POST request fails.

Any suggestion?

Comment: All URLs are case sensitive, this is not an axios problem

Comment: But when we calls it from Axios how to handle the situation. Because by mistake user can type everything in lower case , as I described.

Comment: First off it should probably be a 404 error, you can display an error page and if you can propose a redirection according to typos (e.g. Using Levenshtein's distance)

Comment: @M.Sharma That's why domain names aren't case-sensitive. Users don't type deep link URLs very often.

Comment: Here are two things one ASP.NET CORE and WEB API. My login page is in asp.net core. After successful login I create ClaimsPrincipal and add claims. Controller methods are called from VueJS that I used to create view layer. When I give domain name myweb it does not work. Because internally in C# , code did not find claims and reject the request.

Answer (score 0):

You could use axios interceptor as a hook:

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(function(response) {
    response.url = response.url.toLowerCase();
    return response;
});
```

Comment: But problem is in POST verb.

Comment: I have seen that in my scenario .AspNetCore.Cookies is lost in POST request from vue JS to asp.net core and it returns status code 401.